# Facing difficulties in different environments like visual studio 2010 and visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net

I was using visual studio 2015 and i'd developed the whole project in it but now i'm going to handover this project to my fellow having visual studio 2010 so I'd copied all files and all going good but now i'm facing the error

> "the name does not exist in the current context"

supervisor.aspx.cs

```
protected void DDLQuestion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (DDLQuestion.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0")
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        String query = "Select question_pk,question_number,subject_code ,total_questions,remaining_questions From allotment_status where question_number= " + "'" + DDLQuestion.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()+"'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(ds, "allotment_status");
        GridView2.DataSource = ds;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

supervisor.aspx code

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLQuestion_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    CssClass="dropdown" 
    Width="300px" 
    ID="DDLQuestion" 
    runat="server">

</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: There's missing some information here: Are you facing this error with the project handed back after being modified in VS2010? Did you track changes made? Any code to go with that error?

Comment: yeah after i'd modified it in VS2010 the errors appeared

Comment: Currently the most likely answer would be that `GridView2` has gone missing.

Comment: gridview2 is present in .aspx file

Comment: I'd suggest you use the debugger and find out which *name does not exist*. Having us guess around is useless.

Comment: all tags that were used in supervisor.aspx file are missing in supervisor.aspx.cs file

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing , create a new visual studio 2010 solution and `import` the files . Everything will work fine .

This error frequently occurs if you declare a variable in a loop or a try or if block and then attempt to access it from an enclosing code block or a separate code block.

Better delete the designer file. You can then right-click on the page, in the solution explorer, and there is an option like **`Convert to Web Application`**, which will regenerate your designer file.

Comment: This error frequently occurs if you declare a variable in a loop or a try or if block and then attempt to access it from an enclosing code block or a separate code block.

Comment: Better delete the designer file. You can then right-click on the page, in the solution explorer, and there is an option like "Convert to Web Application", which will regenerate your designer file